# How to send raw data from Android http post request

Tags: http, http-post

I am trying to send an http post request with raw data .

the raw data format is described below

{ "value" : "01712211022" ,"password": "test"} . how can I add the raw data with request URL ?

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Or use the following sample:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

try {

    httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));

    HttpResponse result = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    HttpEntity resultEntity = result.getEntity();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     /**/
} catch (IOException e) {
     /**/
}
```

And don't forget to add these lines to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```